# The correct way to calculate Radians in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pp7oby62/. The fiddle consists of a paddle game with rocks being hurdled at a paddle on a 80x10 sensor grid. The function notify_player has two parameters which give me the location of the rocks and the paddle. My code looks like this:

```
defender.start(

function notify_player(rocks, paddle_y) {
var rocks_x = Math.max(rocks);
var rocks_y = Math.min(rocks);
var paddle_x = Math.max(paddle_y);
var paddle_yp = Math.min(paddle_y);
var deltaY = rocks_y - paddle_yp;
var deltaX = rocks_x - paddle_x;
var angleInRadians = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
var angleRound=Math.round(angleInRadians);
// random plan
var moves = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
    // -1, 0, 1 to move the fiddle up and down on the grid
    //moves.push( Math.floor(Math.random()*3) - 1 );
    if (angleInRadians >0) moves.push(-1);
    else if (angleInRadians < 0) moves.push(0, 1, -1);
}
     return moves;
}
);
```

The moves array controls the paddle moving up and down. As you can see I am calculating the angle in radians using the the information I get from the two parameters. But when I run it there's no effect on the movement of paddle when I give conditional loops stating that the angle is >0 or <0. But suppose I say:

```
if(angleInRadians!==0)
```

The paddle moves. 
How could this be possible?

Comment: Is this a programming test for a job interview?

Comment: How does that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there's no effect on the movement of paddle when I give conditional loops stating that the angle is >0 or <0.

This could simply be when `anleInRadians` is zero - you've got a blind spot there.

> But suppose I say: `if(angleInRadians!==0)` The paddle moves. How could this be possible?

The variable `angleInRadians` contains the value `NaN`. It is neither smaller nor greater than zero, as it's not a number - but it is definitely not zero. Yes, `NaN`s equality relations are a bit odd (it's not even equal to itself).

The reason why you are getting `NaN` here is that you're doing invalid mathematical operations. `rocks` is an array of objects (you really should log and inspect it), which you cannot call `Math.min` or `.max` on.

Btw, it doesn't even make sense to call `min` or `max` on a single value. And you won't get the `paddle_x` position by calling `Math.max(paddle_y)`.